# How to parse string with sscanf_s()?

Tags: c++, scanf

I have the string (45 bytes):

```
        String1        String2000000000001234
```

I need get three variable from this string:

```
char * var1="String1";
char * var2="String2";
int var3=1234;
```

Here 3 part with fixed length (15 bytes). I need save all parts to variable without spaces for strings and without leading zero for integers.

Is this possible with scanf()? How I can to do that?

Comment: Is the series of digits to be skipped fixed at 11 digits?  Are they always zeroes?

Comment: Please give more information, like what delimits what is between what you want to get.  For example, is there always whitespace on both sides of the first string?  Does whitespace always separate the 1st and 2nd string, and is the 2nd string always separated from the `var3` by a leading zero?  How do we tell the difference between "string2" and "1234" from "string" and "20000000001234"?

Comment: Here 3 part with fixed length (15 bytes). I need save all parts to variable without spaces for strings and without leading zero for integers.

Comment: Do you want to remove all spaces from a string, just leading spaces or both leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: Only leading spaces. That is pseudo code, that explain what I want to get with scanf():

 buf="        String1        String2000000000001234";

 var1=trim(substr(buf,0,15));

 var2=trim(substr(buf,15,15));

 var3=(int)substr(buf,30,15);

Answer (score 4):

Not possible with sscanf.  First, you need to pass a char *array* (and size if you use the _s variety) and not just a char pointer (i.e. it needs to have memory associated with it).  Second, strings in sscanf terminate by whitespace, and you have none between String2 and 0000.  Write a custom parser for this format.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html), your problem should be solved by the following format:

```
%*[^a-zA-Z]%s%*[^a-zA-Z]%[^0]s%*[^1-9]%d
```

Description:

%*[^a-zA-Z] - skip(do not store) until alphabetical, i.e. skip leading spaces

%s - read first string until spaces

%*[^a-zA-Z] - skip trailing spaces until the next string

%[^0]s - read string util zeros

%*[^1-9] -skip until nonzero digits

%d - finally, read the number

Comment: This won't work if the strings start with any non-alphabetic characters, such as `-`.  It will also fail if there's no whitespace before the first string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be:

```
char var1_buffer[31] = "", var2_buffer[31] = "";
sscanf(string+30, "%d", &var3);
string[30] = '\0';
sscanf(string, "%s%s", var1_buffer, var2_buffer);
var1 = strdup(var1_buffer);
var2 = strdup(var2_buffer);
```

which requires being able to write to the input string.  If that's not possible, you could replace lines 3 and 4 with:

```
int p1 = 0;
sscanf(string, "%30s %n%30s", var1_buffer, &p1, var2_buffer);
if (p1 > 30)
    p1 = 30;
var2_buffer[30-p1] = '\0';
```

In either case, you should probably add checks of the return value of sscanf to make sure the input string is well-formed.